# If browser is already supporting HTML 5 then do we need to specifiy {display: block;} in css for newer block level tags?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

If browser is already supporting HTML 5 then do we need to specifiy `{display: block;}` in css for newer block level tags?

Generally we don't define `{display: block;}` for HTML 4 block level tags in CSS reset.

So I'm only considering latest Firefox, Safari, IE9 and Mobile Safari and Android browser do i need to keep this

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section
{display: block;}
```

in CSS reset.

Not considering IE 6, 7, 8 and Windows Mobile 7

Comment: I think the point of the reset is to make sure all browsers have the same behavior to start, then build off of that. If in your situation you only have to support browsers that you know will define those elements as block, then you could remove that CSS. As of today, not all browsers define those as block level elements, so it would likely be needed.

Comment: I'm not considering Not considering IE 6, 7, 8, IE Mobile, Windows Mobile 7 Browser and Firefox 2 and Opera's old versions. then is it good to remove this ?

Comment: Prescott is right. Most of a CSS reset isn't required. It's just to make sure all browsers handle all things the same. What's in a name, right?

Comment: @Rudie - I agree. but we never specify `div, p, h1 {display:block}`

Comment: to be honest, I don't know which browsers do or don't support those tags, I don't use them all that much :(

Comment: @Jitendra: No, because *all* browsers see those as block-level elements by default, so that rule would only be superfluous.

Comment: The point of the reset is to waste your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to. It's only necessary for some browsers that didn't understand the new element tags and automatically made them `inline`.

Comment: I think it's only require for IE6, 7, 8, IE Mobile and Firefox 2

Comment: I'm not sure, but at least the browsers specified in your question don't need that reset rule.